# How to set preferred URL in Bing Webmaster Tools

Tags: url, bing-webmaster-tools

My site is `www.example.com` and Bing Webmaster Tools keeping telling me to submit a sitemap for `example.com`, so it is possible to stop Bing stop bothering me the `example.com`?

Answer (score 4):

This functionality doesn't exist for Bing Webmaster Tools.

It considers `example.com` as your domain, whatever the subdomain you can use (`www` or something else). It's not a big deal, just take care of submit a *sitemap.xml* and choosing your preferred version by redirecting on to another on server side. If you use Apache as a web server, you can use these lines in your *.htaccess* (it redirects `no-www` to `www` version):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I always forward example.com to www.example.com, just not sure why Bing is asking for example.com/sitemap.xml..

Comment: If you already forward `example.com` to `www.example.com`, it's perfect. Just don't take into account the message from Bing, it just asks you a sitemap for website you configured.